# How to reconcile data automatically between gitaly nodes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have deployed Gitlab with a separate praefect server and 3 gitaly nodes.
This setup works fine , I am facing issues when i replace an gitaly node with a new server. Data is not getting replicated from other gitaly nodes.

I tried using below command but i got error , as I am using tls connection between praefect and gitaly nodes.

```
sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/praefect -config /var/opt/gitlab/praefect/config.toml reconcile -virtual default -reference gitaly-2 -target gitaly-1 -f
```

Getting below error

```
unable to reconcile: failed to dial "localhost:2305" connection: context deadline exceeded
```

Looking for some pointers on how can I do automatic reconcilation of data between gitaly nodes